# How to View Special character in UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am trying to show special character in UIWebView but it does not show anything.
The line is "100% pure cotton" but at present it shows "100ure cotton"
how i will show it now
thanks in advance

Comment: formatedHtml = [formatedHtml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%" withString:@"&#37"];

this solve is for percentage.
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm  please visit this site for more html codes for special character.Is there any way to solve dynamically.
thanks

Comment: You can use '%' symbol by using keybord or use unicode.